# .NET How to get Domain\Username on server?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I have middleware in startup.cs and I need to get user domain and if his domain is in allowed domains i will send him to windows authentication, if not he must go through web login. This is code:

```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var settings = Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
            var sessionId = context.Session.GetInt32("SessionID");
            if (settings.Login.TwoStepAuthentication is true && sessionId is null)
            {
                List<string> paths = new List<string>() { "/", "/Account/AdLogin/" };
                if (paths.Contains(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"Trying to access {context.Request.Path.Value}");

                    //var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

                    //var identity = context.Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                    var domain = identity.Split(separator: @"\");
                    logger.LogInformation($"Domain name:{domain[0]}");
                    if (!settings.Login.AllowedDomains.Any(x => x.Contains(domain[0])))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AdLogin");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            await next();
        });
```

This works okay on my local machine, and i get Domain\User, however when i deploy my application, i get only "APP POOL" as Domain.

Comment: that sounds like an anonymous user... (not on the current server's domain)  Is your application running under an application pool identity called "APP POOL"?

Comment: Yes, i use application pool identity, for example if I change on local system i get NT AUTHORITY but i need Domain\User, we have application where we need win auth for some users and for others web login, what i'm trying to do is to take domain\user from local machine and check

Comment: where did you deployed your app?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng WIndows Server 2016, IIS (Version 10.0)